# CloudFront Redirection Issue: NLB Istio Override and Custom Domain Loss

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-eks, istio

I have set up an EKS environment and deployed Istio to expose my applications. Upon creating my CloudFront distribution pointing to my Istio NLB, the URL "abc123.cloudfront.net" redirects to my NLB at "abc-123.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" instead of maintaining "abc123.cloudfront.net." I have also configured an alias with a custom domain, "example.com," and still face the redirection issue.

I performed a curl command and consistently receive a 301 status code:

```bash
curl --head --location https://example.com
HTTP/2 301
content-length: 0
location: https://abc-123.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/
date: Sun, 28 Jan 2024 21:52:30 GMT
server: istio-envoy
x-cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
via: 1.1 93fdc54a207de431301d71c9b3644446.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: GRU3-P5
x-amz-cf-id: O4Jr0UNuqtEN_DzuVSl9EIh3f0WZZK4hI7mVnwYySM0Zn3esBLCOlg==
age: 3612
```

What could be causing this 301 redirect and preventing the maintenance of the custom domain?

What I Tried:
I created an EKS environment and deployed Istio to expose my applications (Gateway/VirtualService). I set up a CloudFront distribution pointing to my Istio NLB. Additionally, I configured an alias with a custom domain, "example.com."

Expectations:
I expected the URL "abc123.cloudfront.net" to maintain its original domain instead of redirecting to the NLB at "abc-123.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com." The alias with the custom domain, "example.com," was also anticipated to function without redirection. However, I consistently receive a 301 status code during curl requests, indicating a redirection issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm create a AAAA in Route53 to Cloudfront and this and it worked.
I was very confused, because in my CloudFront configurations I am only accepting IPv4, I did not find information about this from CloudFront.